# Spring Data Mongodb not sorting properly on null values

Tags: spring, mongodb, sorting

I am facing one issue while using the mongodb sorting. By default sorting takes place on null values as first elements for ascending order and last elements in descending order. For one of my requirement i have to display all null values at last place irrespective of the sorting order.

If it is single column, it should be fine. But i have to sort on multiple fields at a time. And for all the fields it has to take consider all null values as last values.

Is there any way that Mongodb supports for this. I am using spring data. Thought spring sort provides the feature of Null Last as the parameter, some how it is not working.

Comment: Please provide more information e.g. code you already tried which didnt work. Also please share more information about your environment.

Answer (score 2):

You can sort your fields this way:

```
Sort sort = new Sort(
            new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.DESC, "firstField", Sort.NullHandling.NULLS_LAST),
            new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.ASC, "secondField", Sort.NullHandling.NULLS_LAST),
            new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.ASC, "thirdField", Sort.NullHandling.NULLS_FIRST));
```

Comment: This isn't supported for MongoDB. It works for SQL queries i.e., RDMS.

Comment: @FaisalFeroz can you point me to documentation that confirms this?  Thanks

Comment: I don't think there is any mention of this being supported (or not supported) in Spring Data Mongo documentation but if you traverse through the code you won't find any reference of this in Spring Data MongoDB implementation but you will find Spring Data JPA.